# Knockout Component and RequireJs Content Not Found under Asp MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-components

I am trying to use components binding way with KnockoutJs and RequireJs,
but I got simple issue that I can't solve.

I have created a folder under my Asp MVC 4 solution `/SomeName/SomeSubName` and
I have created 2 files under this folder: `mycmt.js` and `mycmt.html`

In my cshtml I added the following html:

```
<RefEditorWindow params="value: someMyProp"></RefEditorWindow>
```

JS code part

```
ko.components.register('RefEditorWindow', {
            viewModel: { require: 'SomeName/SomeSubName/mycmt' },
            template: { require: 'text!SomeName/SomeSubName/mycmt.html' }
        });
```

inside of mycmt.js

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {

    function RefEditorWindowViewModel(params) {
        this.updatedDepartment = params.value;
    }

    return RefEditorWindowViewModel;    
});
```

I don't see any errors in console but on binding logic, I tried to show this component and see an error:

> *Content not found*

How to fix it? Why required can't load or find files.

Comment: Why do you use this custom component in your cshtml files? Aren't cshtml files supposed to generated server side? (Can you give some more information about your project structure?)

Comment: I just would like to use something new for me in knokoutjs